# Return all ServiceNow table contents using Azure API

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management, servicenow, apim

I am new to Azure APIM and in API in general. I'm trying to create an API that will call out any ServiceNow table.

I came across below policy from another API but it only works to some of the table. It returns contents with values but for some, it returns empty without any contents (not even fields/columns of the table) at all. It's just showing:

```
{
"result": []
}
```

In which part of the code should I update this? How can I make this generic so it will return all contents regardless of which table is being called?

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cache-lookup-value key="SNow1" variable-name="SNow1" caching-type="internal" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(!context.Variables.ContainsKey("SNow1"))">
                <cache-lookup-value key="SNow2" variable-name="SNow2" caching-type="internal" />
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@(context.Variables.ContainsKey("SNow2"))">
                        <send-request ignore-error="true" timeout="30" response-variable-name="SNowResponse" mode="new">
                            <set-url>https://{{ServiceNow---host}}/oauth_token.do</set-url>
                            <set-method>POST</set-method>
                            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                                <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
                            </set-header>
                            <set-body>@{
                                Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                                    { "grant_type", "refresh_token" },
                                    { "refresh_token", (string) context.Variables["SNow2"] },
                                    { "client_id", "{{ServiceNow----client-id}}" },
                                    { "client_secret", "{{ServiceNow----client-secret}}" }
                                };
                                return parameters.Select(parameter => $"{parameter.Key}={parameter.Value}").Aggregate((accum, parameter) => $"{accum}&{parameter}");
                            }</set-body>
                        </send-request>
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <send-request ignore-error="true" timeout="30" response-variable-name="SNowResponse" mode="new">
                            <set-url>https://{{ServiceNow---host}}/oauth_token.do</set-url>
                            <set-method>POST</set-method>
                            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                                <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
                            </set-header>
                            <set-body>@{
                                Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                                    { "grant_type", "password" },
                                    { "client_id", "{{ServiceNow----client-id}}" },
                                    { "client_secret", "{{ServiceNow----client-secret}}" },
                                    { "username", "{{ServiceNow----username-SN}}" },
                                    { "password", "{{ServiceNow----password-SN}}" }
                                };
                                return parameters.Select(parameter => $"{parameter.Key}={parameter.Value}").Aggregate((accum, parameter) => $"{accum}&{parameter}");
                            }</set-body>
                        </send-request>
                    </otherwise>
                </choose>
                <set-variable name="SNow3" value="@(((IResponse) context.Variables["SNowResponse"]).Body.As<JObject>())" />
                <set-variable name="SNow1" value="@((string) ((JObject) context.Variables["SNow3"])["access_token"])" />
                <set-variable name="SNow1Duration" value="@((int) ((JObject) context.Variables["SNow3"])["expires_in"])" />
                <set-variable name="SNow2" value="@((string) ((JObject) context.Variables["SNow3"])["refresh_token"])" />
                <cache-store-value key="SNow1" value="@((string) context.Variables["SNow1"])" duration="@((int) context.Variables["SNow1Duration"])" caching-type="internal" />
                <cache-store-value key="SNow2" value="@((string) context.Variables["SNow2"])" duration="{{ServiceNow---refresh-token-expiry-time}}" caching-type="internal" />
            </when>
        </choose>
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://{{ServiceNow---host}}" />
        <rewrite-uri template="@($"/api/now/table/{context.Request.MatchedParameters["tableName"]}")" />
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>@($"Bearer {(string) context.Variables["SNow1"]}")</value>
        </set-header>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Comment: Did you check the trace log?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer in the tracelog, it